# Error in Tableau Custom Query

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

I have written the following query in Tableau as a custom query but as I have 2 fields with the same name I get the following error message:

```
Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "Custom SQL Query"."EID": invalid identifier
```

and I am not sure how to fix this.

My query is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 Q FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 C ON Q.EID = C.EID
```

Would appreciate any advice on how I can fix this.

Comment: It's not because you have two fields the same name. `invalid identifer` means there is no field called `EID` in one or both tables. Make sure this field exists in both tables. Try this: `select EID from Table1` and this: `select eid from Table2` seperately. Do they both work?

Comment: What about listing the columns you need in the select clause instead of using the * ? I would also recommend to avoid spaces in the name of your custom query as it looks like it's used in the query fired against the DB.

Comment: Thanks guys, will take your suggestions and let you know how I get on.